# getting data into crystal report from two tables

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i have two tables,first one is having personal information of employee.
and second one is having payment details of emp.
i want to print personal information and payment details on same crystal report.
but while doing it,i  am facing problem that ,with multiple payment details ,multiple times personal information is printed.that personal info should printed only once.
how it should be solved?

Comment: Can you post a snap shot of your design?

Comment: i dont have reputation for posting snap shot.plz give me ur mail id.thanks

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I suppose you should create a view in database

Comment: thanks,ur suggestion worked.thank u very much

Comment: i have another problem with crystal report.if there r 40 to 50 char in a cell of table and if i print that cell in crystal report, only first 7 to 8 char prints.how should size be increased

Comment: You should be able to increase the width of the database field in the crystal report designer .

Comment: THAT PROBLEM IS ALSO SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the employee details in the `Page Header Section` and the payment details in the `Details Section`. See Image below :

[image]